# How to print response data to csv in jmeter

Tags: csv, null, jmeter

I want to write response data which is as follows:

"Email": "xyz@gmail.com",
"message": "my message"

I want to knw how to write specific response in csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have response data which looks like:

```
{
  "Email": "xyz@gmail.com",
  "message": "my message"
}
```

you can save the values into a file like:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above data
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

   new File('user_details.csv') << response.Email << ',' << response.message << System.getProperty('line.separator')
   ```
3. That's it, you now should see the values in the `user_details.csv` file

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

---

If you want to go your way ([although using Beanshell is not recommended](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)) - make sure to extract these `Email` and `message` bits using i.e. [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)

Comment: thanks Dmitri, it works but its not writing email. I can see message is proper but Email is still null.

Comment: Groovy is case-sensitive, maybe you need to change `Email` to `email` or so

Comment: its "email" and I have already mentioned it as "email"  but no output.